# Electron how apply style on primary window when second window closes?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a preferences window where I define colors, then I trigger an alert when window closes

```
window.on('close', function () {
        window = null 
        writePreferences(inputs)
        win.webContents.send("PREFERENCE_SAVED", 'saved')
})
```

Then on my front-end js I have this

```
ipcRenderer.on(PREFERENCE_SAVED, (event , data) => {
  document.querySelector('html').style.setProperty("--background", "orange")
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for sending and receiving messages is:

To send from the window to the renderer:

```
win.webContents.send('asynchronous-message', 'message');
```

To receive the message in renderer:

```
ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-message', function (event, message) {
    // Do your background color changing here.
});
```

So your code would become something like this:

Main:

```
window.on('close', function () {
    window = null
    writePreferences(inputs)
    win.webContents.send('asynchronous-message', "PREFERENCE_SAVED");
})
```

Renderer:

```
ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-message', function (event, message) {
    if (message == 'PREFERENCE_SAVED') {
        document.querySelector('html').style.setProperty("--background", "orange");
    }
});
```

[`ipcRenderer.on` Docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendereronchannel-listener)

[`win.webContents.send` Docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-arg1-arg2-)